# Sequence of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $f \in L^1([0,1])$ be a non negative, finite function. Show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{f(x)}dx=m(\{x \in [0,1]/f(x)>0\}$$

This is what I could do:

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{f(x)}$. If $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$, if $f(x)>0$, then $f_n(x) \to 1$. So $f_n(x) \to \mathcal X_S$, where $S=\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)>0\}$.

Since $m(\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)>0\})=\int_0^1\mathcal X_Sdx$, then all I have to show is 
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_ndx=\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty}f_ndx$$

I don't know which property allows me to affirm that the limit of the integrals is the integral of the limit, I am not under the hypothesis of the monotone convergence theorem ($f_n(x)$ is increasing for $x:f(x) \geq 1$ and decreasing if not), I cannot apply the dominated convergence theorem since from the information of the problem I can't assure there exists $g$ integrable with $|f_n|\leq  |g|$).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in[0,1]$, define
$$
g(x):=\max\{f(x), 1\}.
$$
Then $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$: we have equality if $f(x)\geq1$, and if $f(x)\leq 1$ then $\sqrt[n]{f(x)}\leq 1$ for all $n$.

Can you prove that $g(x)$ is integrable?  If so, then the Dominated Convergence Theorem will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

By Fatou's lemma, $\varliminf \int_0^1 f_n\, dx \ge \int_0^1 \chi_S\, dx = m(f > 0)$. On the other hand, by Holder's inequality, $$\int f_n\, dx = \int \chi_Sf_n\, dx \le m(f > 0)^{1 - 1/n} \|f\|_1^{1/n}.$$

Hence $\varlimsup \int f_n\, dx \le m(f > 0)$. Consequently, $\lim \int f_n\, dx = m(f > 0)$.